# Overflow em menu off canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

estou fazendo um menu `off canvas`, na verdade ele está sempre na tela, e quando eu clico no botão, o que se move é o meu `main`, o problema está sendo o overflow, quando eu abro o menu ele não deveria deixar eu dar `scroll`, mas sim fechar o menu, caso eu clique em qualquer coisa fora do mesmo. Mas ele está me dando `overflow` na página toda. alguma sugestão? PS: Tirei a inspiração deste site, crédito a eles, http://www.x-apps.com.br/ .

```js
var menu = false;
$('#hamburguer').click(function() {
    if (menu === false) {
      mostraCanvas();
    } else {
      escondeCanvas();
    }
});

function escondeCanvas() {
    $("#main").css("padding-left", "0");
    $("html, body").css("overflow", "auto");

    menu = false;
}

function mostraCanvas() {
  $("#main").css("padding-left", "50vw");
  $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden");
  menu = true;
}

$('.off-item').click(function() {
    escondeCanvas();
});
```

```css
.off-canvas{
  padding-top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #292929;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
#main{
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 !important;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: padding .2s linear;
  -moz-transition: padding .2s linear;
  -o-transition: padding .2s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
      <div class="topo" id="topo">
      <button id="hamburguer"><h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger blue btn-nav"></span></h1><button>
    </div>
      <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
         <ul>
            <a href="#banner" id="linkbanner">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <h2>Inicio</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#sobremim">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <h2>Sobre Mim</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#portfolio">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <h2>Portfólio</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#habilidades">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <h2>Habilidades</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#contato">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <h2>Contato</h2>
               </li>
            </a>
         </ul>
      </nav>
    blablabla até o fim do main...
  </div>
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor onde deve clicar para abrir e para fechar?

Comment: @sergio note aquele H1 dentro da div "topo" dentro, é nele que eu clico, é que como eu estava apenas fazendo testes não usei o `button`

Comment: @TiagoSilveira Não consigo simular o problema. O que está tendo Overflow que não deveria? Aqui eu não consigo dar scroll no conteúdo depois de abrir o menu. Parece correto.

Comment: @leonfreire entre, por favor no https://tiagosilveiraa.github.io/ entre nas ferramentas mobile (ou pelo celular mesmo), clique no icone do menu e dê o scroll, note o comportamento do body, ele não deveria dar scroll, ele deveria fechar o menu. Grato se puder me ajudar :)

Comment: @TiagoSilveira Retirei a minha resposta por causa dos outros problemas. Se eu conseguir resolver tudo, volto a postar.

Comment: Muito obrigado @leonfreire , continuarei buscando a solução também.

Answer (score 1):

Cheguei a ver que você fez algumas atualizações no site e hoje fiz uns testes com a sua versão atual. Tenta as seguintes mudanças para ver se te dá resultado. (Como estou testando em uma versão baixada do seu site, não consigo ver com 100% de fidelidade.)

### No seu script:

```
function escondeCanvas() {
    $("#main").css("padding-left", "0");
    $("body").css("overflow-x", "");
    $("nav").removeClass("open");
    menu = false;
}

function mostraCanvas() {
  $("#main").css("padding-left", "50vw");
  $("body").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
  $("nav").addClass("open");
  menu = true;
}
```

### No seu CSS:

```
nav.open {
    z-index: 1;
}
nav.open + #main {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Poxa, amigo, resolveu mesmo, mas agora os links não clicam, alguma sugestão? Ou melhor, os links não são clicaveis...

Comment: outra coisa é quando eu volto o main para o lugar o scroll continua desabilitado :/

Comment: @TiagoSilveira Veja se estas mudanças te ajudam.

Comment: @TiagoSilveira Calma que reparei que ainda continua no corte. Mas eu tinha resolvido e só esqueci de adicionar ali. Vou ver de novo! xD

Comment: @TiagoSilveira Agora sim. Vê aí!

Comment: funcionou, mas quando eu ativo o menu ele automaticamente dá o scroll para o topo da página, deve ser por causa do Overflow-y, algum hack para tal?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60073/discussion-between-tiago-silveira-and-leon-freire).